# How To Get Postfix To Produce Logs

Tags: logging, postfix-mta, systemd

I have recently setup an email server that uses Postfix, Dovecot and Mysql (mariaDB) on CentOS 7. It is working, however, Postfix is not producing a log file ANYWHERE.  Postfix is most likely not logging because I was unable to configure this correctly.  The following settings in /etc/postfix/main.cf do not produce logs:

```
syslog_facility  = local1
syslog_name = postfix
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

OK, it seems that I was looking completely in the wrong place.  CentOS is moving from rsyslog to systemd-journald, and rsyslogd is not even running.  Since I downloaded the postfix source code, compiled and installed it myself I didn't realize that I shouldn't be looking in log files for the requested information.  In order to see this information for Postfix I have to run the command

```
journalctl -u postfix
```

or something similar for systemd-journald